# How to connect Backbone, Mocha, Chai, Require.js and Sinon

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I’m currently trying to setup a testing environment for my app based on Backbone. I want to unit test some of the functions. But I have to admit I have problems connecting the different components. I am working with Backbone, Mocha, Chai, expect.js, require.js and Sinon. The app was basically setup with Yeoman some time ago. What I built up for now is (based on this tutorial which I liked a lot: https://puigcerber.com/2013/12/23/using-grunt-to-run-mocha-tests-with-backbone-js-and-requirejs/)

In my root I have a folder called test, which contains:

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Mocha Spec Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"     href="../app/ressources/bower_components/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="mocha"> </div>

<script src="../node_modules/sinon-1.17.3.js"></script>
<script src="../app/ressources/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
<script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
<script src="../app/ressources/bower_components/chai/chai.js"></script>
<script>var expect = chai.expect</script>

<script data-main="spec/runner" src="../app/ressources/bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and a folder called spec, including:

my runner.js:

```
'use strict';
require.config({
baseUrl: '../app/',
paths: {
    jquery: 'ressources/bower_components/jquery/jquery',
    backbone: 'ressources/bower_components/backbone/backbone',
    underscore: 'ressources/bower_components/underscore/underscore',
    text: 'ressources/bower_components/text/text',
    deepmodel: 'ressources/bower_components/backbone-deep-model/distribution/deep-model.min'
},
shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    jquery: {
        exports: '$'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }
}
});

var specs = [
   'spec/test.js'
];

require(specs, function() {

if (window.mochaPhantomJS) {
    mochaPhantomJS.run();
}
else {
    mocha.run();
}
});
```

and my test.js:

```
'use strict';
define(function(require) {
var ExamplesCollection = require('collections/OrganisationsCollection');

describe('Examples collection', function() {

    var examples = new OrganisationCollection();

    it('should exist', function() {
        expect(examples).to.exist;
    });

    it('should be an instance of Examples collection', function() {
        expect(examples).to.be.an.instanceof(OrganisationsCollection);
    });

});

});
```

The test.js is really only a test, what I really want to do is:

```
beforeEach(function() {

    this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    this.Organisations = new OrganisationsCollection({id:7, name:'somestring’});
    var searchString = 'test';
    this.responseBody  = '[{"id":7,"name":"somestring"}]';

    this.server.respondWith("GET", ‘myUrl’,
    [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},this.responseBody]);
    });


afterEach(function() {
    this.server.restore();
});


it('should return full list, function () {

    var fetchSpy = sinon.spy(this.Organisations, "fetch");
     this.Organisations.fetch();
     this.server.respond();
     var response = fetchSpy.getCall(0).returnValue.responseText;
     response.should.equal(this.responseBody);

   });
```

I just want to test, if the Collection fetch is working. I thought about mocking the Service, which is calling the fetch within a function, but I didn’t found a possibility for that. So I wanted to fake the sinon server to check my fetch.

I always have the problem that I can’t instantiate my Service, where the Collection is called, which makes no testing possible.

So sadly, nothing is really working.

I get 2 kinds of error:

When I start my test using grunt on the console, I get the error: **Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue**.

I am getting this, since I am using the runner.js file. When I called the mocha.run() directly in the index, I hadn’t had this issue, but some other issues concerning require.js.

The other problem is when I call my test in the browser. There I get different errors:

**ReferenceError: OrganisationCollection is not defined (test.js)**

And some erros concerning my path loadings in runner.js

So none of my components are working together. I googled for days and tried lots of ways, but none of them is working for me.

I have to say I am really new to this topic and would be so incredibly glad, if someone out there could help me.

Comment: *"I always have the problem that I can’t instantiate my Service*" - What do you mean by instantiating service? You are getting the reference error because of the path errors. did you check what is wrong with the file paths?

Comment: What I suggest is you break things up. First try running a very simple test, like something that checks if a view is defined, which doesn't need any fake services. If you have problems with that, ask a question regarding that, leave sinon and stuff out of it. Once you get it working, then try to set up sinon. If you face issues, explain the working setup and how you tried setting up sinon in a new question. if you get errors in a specific environment during any of this process, explain your current working setup and ask a question why it isn't working on the other environment

Comment: My service is the module, where I call the function, I want to test. To call that function, I have to somehow instantiate the service in my test, right? The file path to the service is absolutely correct, so I don't know what the problem is here.

Comment: To your second post: I got a simple test running, but when I wanted to use Sinon I had to switch from calling Mocha in my index to the runner.js so I can include everything I need (has something to do with require.js I think). From there, nothing was working any more. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out, what the problem was: Actually, the problem was my Gruntfile.js:

```
  test: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                base: [
                    'node_modules',
                    '.tmp',
                    'test',
                    '<%= projectFolders.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
```

I wasn't using the paths right, so my requires had to look like this:

```
jquery: 'ressources/bower_components/jquery/jquery'
```

because I was already in the app folder.

The second error was also in the Gruntfile.js:

```
  mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                log: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    }
```

I had do delete the run:true.

From now on, the components work perfectly fine together.